# Removing File URL with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am writing a program and run it locally with xampp. the full path to the program is http://192.168.101.103:7777/WeltesMaft/index.php

I am writing a .htaccess in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesMaft\ 
containing this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule .*  http://192.168.101.103:7777/WeltesMaft/%1 [L]
```

but somehow my htaccess doesnt work. it still showing like this

```
http://192.168.101.103:7777/WeltesMart/_resources/main.php
```

which is in index.php i am including main.php. So when user enters index.php, it will redirect to main.php in an instant.

I want to hide it so that the url looks like this,

```
http://192.168.101.103:7777/WeltesMart/
```

Please help me what am i doing wrong here...

Comment: this isn't javascript, php, html or oracle related

Comment: You're requirement is very confusing and doesn't seem to make sense.  Where does this come from `http://192.168.100.195:7777/WeltesMart/_resources/main.php`?

Comment: my bad... im sorry. I edited my question

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code also.....

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>   
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ _resources/main.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `RewriteBase` to your directory name and change the htaccess rule as following and try again:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /WeltesMaft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule / index.php [L]
```